# JNLP File not updated

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

We are distributing our clients with Java Webstart.

Our JNLP File:

```
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="http://{host}/jws/cashdesk/" href="cashdesk.jnlp"
version="3.4.2">
<information>
    <title>Kasse {appserver}</title>
    <description>Kasse</description>
    <icon href="cashdesk{rem}.png" />
    <shortcut online="true">
        <desktop />
    </shortcut>
</information>
<update check="always" policy="always" />
<security>
    <all-permissions />
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-Xmx512M" />
    <property name="APPSERVER" value="{appserver}:1099" />
    <jar href="cashdesk.jar" main="true" />
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="com.prodega.proshop.cashdesk.CashdeskApp" />
</jnlp>
```

The problem we have is when we change something in the JNLP file it is ignored by Java Webstart.

Why does Java Webstart not update the JNLP File?

Thanks for your help.

Simon

Comment: Will you be able to run java Web Start and only updates are not working?

Comment: Updates of the JARs is working but the JNLP itself is not updated.

Comment: Have you purged the WebServer's cache and the client's browser cache?

Comment: I think it's not a server cache problem. I have the same problem when I use javaws directly:
    javaws http://localhost:8080/jws/cashdesk/

Comment: And client browser cache?

Comment: This must be the problem yes. but what now?